# Cannot git clone android source code from remote server

Tags: android, git

Firstly I

```
$ git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base
Cloning into 'base'...
remote: Sending approximately 1.04 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 43200, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (3713/3713)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (1738/1738)
remote: Compressing objects:  99% (27152/27153)
Receiving objects:   4% (36212/787666), 16.81 MiB | 183 KiB/s
```

For a while, the git hung and didn't go ahead,
So I break git and

```
$ git clone http://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base
Cloning into 'base'...
remote: Sending approximately 1.04 GiB ...
remote: Counting objects: 43200, done
remote: Finding sources: 100% (3713/3713)
remote: Getting sizes: 100% (1738/1738)
remote: Compressing objects:  99% (27152/27153)
error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 20075 MiB | 186 KiB/s
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
fatal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Now it failed as above, I tried several times and every time got same error as above.

How to resolve or workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've met the same problem when git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base.
The "Receiving objects" progress was always shown as 4%.

Unfortunately, I can't get the answer about solving this problem.
So I've changed the remote url to github:

git clone https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base.git

It works now without any problem.